# Changes to copies of object mutate original object

Tags: python, pandas, oop

I have a class within which there is a DataFrame type property. I want to be able to perform arithmetic on the objects using the built-ins while keeping the original objects immutable. Unfortunately, the operations seem to be mutating the original objects as well. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Container:

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame()

    def generate(self):
        self.data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=['A'])
        return self

    def __add__(self, other):
        copy = self
        new = Container()
        new.data['A'] = copy.data.eval(f"A + {0}".format(other))

        return new


one = Container().generate()
two = one + 1

print(one.data == two.data)
```

I think the problem is the `copy = self` line, but I can't seem to preserve the original object even using the copy() method.

How do I make sure the original object doesn't change when a new one is created from it?

Comment: `copy = self` is not a copy.

Comment: What is `f"A + {0}"`?  A typo?

Comment: ...hey, yeah, `f"A + {0}".format(other)` doesn't make sense. That does string formatting with an f-string, and then calls `format` on the result. That should actually fail, because there's no formatting placeholder left for `format` after f-string processing.

Comment: Apparently the `format` argument gets ignored. I could have sworn that only happened for keyword arguments.

Comment: I updated my question to fix the typo - this example was working but the typo only existed in my reproduction code above. Since this was still happening in the original code, I ended up fixing it by doing `new = copy(self)` and `new.data = copy(self.data)`. Sub-optimal but functional

Comment: @rgk: If this code has a different bug from your real bug, post a new question with a revised example that exhibits the same bug as your real code.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, while `copy = self` isn't a copy, your bug doesn't actually have anything to do with that. I don't think you even need a copy there.

Your bug is due to double-formatting a string:

```
f"A + {0}".format(other)
```

`f"A + {0}"` is an f-string. Unlike `format`, it evaluates the text `0` as a Python expression and substitutes the string representation of the resulting object into the resulting string, producing `"A + 0"`. Calling `format` on that doesn't do anything, since there's no format placeholder left. You end up calling

```
copy.data.eval("A + 0")
```

instead of adding what you wanted to add.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question qualifies for a typo close, particularly whether the problem was actually a typo and whether it fits "unlikely to help future readers", but I felt the f-string/format interaction warranted an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Did you `deepcopy`?

```
from copy import deepcopy
dupe=deepcopy(thing)
#now thing and dupe are two separate objects
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I just tried `copy = deepcopy(self)` and `one` is still being modified.